# Principal Component analysis by eigenvalue decomposition.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I do know how to perform PCA by using SVD but I am unaware about how to use eigenvalue decomposition of X(transpose)*X matrix. I found a paper online which explains the approach to perform PCA by using eigen decomposition. But, it does not clearly explain all the stuff. Is there a simple explanation for this. Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, SVD is usually defined (and certainly first taught) in terms of eigen decomposition.  Do you define the SVD in terms of eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $X^TX$?  If not, then how **do** you define it?

Answer (score 0):

Doing SVD on the matrix $X$ is (almost) the same as doing the eigenvalue-decomposition of the covariance matrix $X^T X$ (Note that $X$ is symmetric and hence diagonalizable using eigenvalue decomposition). In general, doing SVD on $X$ is better than forming the covariance matrix and then doing eigenvalue decomposition, which could lead to additional loss of accuracy.