# Are covariance matrices guaranteed to have real-valued eigenvectors and eigenvalues (related to PCA)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm a software engineering, and I'm trying to learn [principal components analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis).

I've read that as part of PCA, I need to compute a covariance matrix and then find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of that matrix.

However, from my understanding, not all square matrices with real numbers have real eigenvectors. See this question "[Do all square matrices have eigenvectors?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654465/do-all-square-matrices-have-eigenvectors/654470)".

Thus, how can a covariance matrix be guaranteed to have eigenvectors and eigenvalues? Could the eigenvectors have complex numbers (that wouldn't seem to be useful for PCA, I would guess)?

Comment: Because it is symmetric: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1243276/principal-component-analysis-by-eigenvalue-decomposition/1243319#1243319

Comment: @MiguelAtencia: Thanks. Are you saying that all real-valued, *symmetric* matrices must have real-valued eigenvectors?

Comment: Covariance matrices are symmetric, so are guaranteed to have real eigenvalues and real eigenvectors by the spectral theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Thank you. Please consider making your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A$ be an $n$-by-$n$ covariance matrix, which must be Hermitian or real symmetric if $A$ is real.  It's simple to see that all eigenvalues of $A$ must be real.  Suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.  Then $Ax=\lambda x$ for some non-zero vector $x$.  So clearly $x^*Ax=x^*\lambda x=\lambda \|x\|^2$.  But since $A=A^*$, we also have $x^*Ax=x^*A^*x=\bar\lambda x^*x=\bar\lambda\|x\|^2$.  Hence $\lambda=\bar\lambda$, i.e. it must be real.

The eigenvectors of $A$ (real symmetric) need not *all* be real.  However, it's always *possible* find a real eigenvector for each eigenvalue of $A$.  To see this, suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, i.e. $Ax=\lambda x$ or $(A-\lambda I)x=0$ for some non-zero $x$.  We've shown that $\lambda$ must be real.  This implies that $(A-\lambda I)$ is real and singular.  Therefore, solving this real linear set of equations can definitely yield a real non-zero solution for $x$, which is an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to $\lambda$.  (Note that $jx$ is also an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to $\lambda$, and it's not real.)

Alternatively, suppose $x=u+jv$ is a complex eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to $\lambda$.  Then $Ax=\lambda x$ means $A(u+jv)=\lambda(u+jv)$, implying that $Au=\lambda u$ and $Av=\lambda v$, since $\lambda$ is real.  So $u$ and $v$ are real eigenvectors of $A$ corresponding to $\lambda$, if they are non-zero.  (They can't both be zero.)

In fact, stronger statements can be made.  Using the above argument repeatedly in the Schur Triangularization process, we can further show that $A$ can be diagonalized by a real orthogonal matrix, i.e. $U^*AU=D$, where $U$ is real orthogonal and $D$ is real diagonal.  So $U$ consists of $n$ real orthogonal eigenvectors of $A$, which diagonalize $A$ and also form a basis for $R^n$.

Comment: (we can also prove [it using the SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Statement_of_the_theorem))